# Snakemake doesn't activate conda environment correctly

Tags: python, conda, snakemake

I have a Python module `modulename` installed in a conda environment called `myenvname`.

My `snakemake` file consists of one simple rule:

```
rule checker2:
    output:
        "tata.txt"
    conda:
        "myenvname"
    script:
        "scripts/test2.py"
```

The contents of the `test2.py` are the following:

```
import modulename
with open("tata.txt","w") as _f:
    _f.write(modulename.__version__)
```

When I run the above snakemake file with the command `snakemake -j 1 --use-conda --conda-frontend conda` I get `ModuleNotFoundError`, which would imply that there is no `modulename` in my specified environment. However, when I do the following :

```
conda activate myenvname
python workflow/scripts/test2.py
```

... everything works perfectly. I have no idea what's going on.

The full error is pasted below, with some info omitted for privacy.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/OMITTED/.snakemake/scripts/tmpheaxuqjn.test2.py", line 13, in <module>
    import cnvpytor as cnv
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MODULENAME'
[Thu Nov 17 18:27:22 2022]
Error in rule checker2:
    jobid: 0
    output: tata.txt
    conda-env: MYENVNAME

RuleException:
CalledProcessError in line 12 of /OMITTED/workflow/snakefile:
Command 'source /apps/qiime2/miniconda3/bin/activate 'MYENVNAME'; set -euo pipefail;  /OMITTED/.conda/envs/snakemake/bin/python3.1 /OMITTED/.snakemake/scripts/tmpheaxuqjn.test2.py' returned non-zero exit status 1.
  File "/OMITTED/workflow/snakefile", line 12, in __rule_checker2
  File "/OMITTED/.conda/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.10/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 58, in run
Shutting down, this might take some time.
Exiting because a job execution failed. Look above for error message
Complete log: /OMITTED/.snakemake/log/2022-11-17T182715.495739.snakemake.log
```

EDIT:
Typo in script fixed, the typo isn't in the script I'm running so it's not the issue here.

EDIT2:
I've tried two different attempts from comments. All three attempts
are run with the same CLI command `snakemake -j 1 --use-conda --conda-frontend conda`

## Attempt 1

Rule in the snakemake:

```
rule checker3:
    output:
        "tata.txt"
    conda:
        "myenvname"
    shell:
        """
        conda env list >> {output}
        conda list >> {output}
        """
```

In the output file I had the following (I have lots of environs and packages I've cut out):

```
# conda environments:
#
...
myenvname              *  /OMITTED/.conda/envs/myenvname
...
# packages in environment at /OMITTED/.conda/envs/myenvname:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
...
modulename                  1.2                       dev_0    <develop>
...
```

This attempt proves that the conda environment is activated and that this environment has `modulename`.

## Attempt 2

Same as running the script, but I've modified the script to include

```
import time; time.sleep(30); import modulename
```

So I can snag a runnable script before it's deleted. The script has the following inserted at the start:

```
######## snakemake preamble start (automatically inserted, do not edit) ########
import sys; sys.path.extend(['/OMITTED/.conda/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.10/site-packages', '/OMITTED/MYWORKINGDIRECTORY/workflow/scripts']); import pickle; snakemake = pickle.loads(####a lot of stuff here###); from snakemake.logging import logger; logger.printshellcmds = False; __real_file__ = __file__; __file__ = '/OMITTED/MYWORKINGDIRECTORY/workflow/scripts/test3.py';
######## snakemake preamble end #########
```

I have no idea what to do with this information.

## Attempt 3

Instead of running script, I've ran a shell command that runs a python script.

```
rule checker4:
    output:
        "tata.txt"
    conda:
        "myenvname"
    shell:
        "python workflow/scripts/test3.py"
```

It worked (showed no errors), and when I open "tata.txt" I find "1.2" which is the version of of my module.

## Conclusions

The snakemake actually activates proper environment, but the problem is in `script` part. I have no idea why this is.

There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69982001/snakemake-cannot-succesfully-load-a-conda-environment), so this is a duplicate question.

Comment: *"`/OMITTED/.conda/envs/snakemake/bin/python3.1 `"* - is that just a typo? What version of Conda is this? I thought they fixed the bug with Python v3.10 being stored as `3.1`. Also, maybe you can snag a copy of the `/OMITTED/.snakemake/scripts/tmpheaxuqjn.test2.py` before it get's deleted. Not sure if that might have additional activation code that could help in debugging.

Comment: I suggest you install `snakemake` in `myenvname` and then try to run the workflow from there (without `--use-conda`) to see if it is really a problem about activating the environment from within snakemake. You can also setup a `rule test_env` with `conda: "myenvname"` and `shell: conda env list; conda list` and call it with `snakemake -c1 --use-conda test_env`. From the output you can determine if you are activating the correct environment and if your package is really installed therein.

Comment: It probably doesn't matter here but your `test2.py` script has a missing quote. `"w)` should be `"w"`. If it all possible try to give a fully reproducible example.

Comment: I've edited the OP with my attempts. tl;dr - It works when I use shell:"python test3.py" and it doesn't work when I use script:"test3.py". I have no idea why this is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question is answered. Snakemake actually activates correct environment, but running a python script with the `script` conflicts with this directive. I don't know if this is a bug in `snakemake` (version is `6.14.0`) or an intentional thing. I've solved the problem by running the python script via `shell` command with `python workflow/scripts/MyScript.py` - it's a bit of a problem because I had to include a CLI wrapper that would normally be solved by a snakemake object.

Comment: This should not be the case. I have many pipelines with R scripts using `script:` + Conda environment. However, could be a version issue - I mostly used `5.8` and `6.10`.